# React-native navigation 'Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined' using redux connect

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I'm creating a react-native app, using expo, **redux** and **react-navigation**, using Typescript.

I want to do a LoginScreen, and when user is logged in, navigate to a MainScreen with a bottom navbar. In a nutshell:

1. LoginScreen
2. MainScreen

   2.1. Orders

   2.2. Settings

In order to do this, I followed this [post](https://medium.com/@jan.hesters/building-a-react-native-app-with-complex-navigation-using-react-navigation-85a479308f52) :

```
const AppNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({OrdersContainer, SettingsScreen});

const LoginNavigator = createStackNavigator({ LoginContainer, RegisterContainer});

const RootNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({ LoginNavigator, AppNavigator });
```

Then, the there is the typical flow with redux. When the login button is pressed, the action for login does a dispatch, and then the reducer updates the state.

Then, the componentDidUpdate in the LoginScreen it's called:

```
componentDidUpdate(currentProps: LoginScreenProps) {
  var accessToken =  currentProps.user.accountInfo.accessToken;
  if(accessToken) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("OrdersContainer");
  };
}

function mapStateToProps(state: AppState): LoginScreenProps {
  return {
    user: state.user
  } as LoginScreenProps;
}
```

Now, when  'navigate' is executed, the following Exception is throwed:

```
TypeError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
This error is located at:
in Connect(OrdersScreen) (at withNavigation.js:23)
in withNavigation(Connect(OrdersScreen)) (at SceneView.js:9)
in SceneView (at StackViewLayout.js:478)
in RCTView (at View.js:60)
in View (at StackViewLayout.js:477)
in RCTView (at View.js:60)
in View (at StackViewLayout.js:476)
in RCTView (at View.js:60)
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!!

**Edit**: Added OrdersScreen file

```js
interface OrderScreenProps {
  Orders: Map<string, Order[]>;
  customer: Customer;
  user: User;
  navigation: NavigationScreenProp<NavigationState, NavigationParams>;

  listOrders: (customer: Customer, user: User) => OrderAction<Order[]>;
}


export class OrdersScreen extends React.Component<OrderScreenProps> {

  static navigationOptions = {
      header: (
        <View style={headerStyles.container}>
          <Text style={headerStyles.text}>Orders</Text>
        </View>
      )
  };

  constructor(props: OrderScreenProps) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return  <OrderListView 
              Orders={this.props.Orders}
            />;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.listOrders(this.props.customer, this.props.user);
  }

}

function mapStateToProps(state: AppState): OrderScreenProps {
  return {
      user: state.user,
      customer: state.customer
  } as OrderScreenProps;
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>) {
  return bindActionCreators({
    listOrders: listOrdersActionCreator
  }, dispatch);
}


const OrdersContainer = withNavigation(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(OrdersScreen));

export { OrdersContainer };
```

Comment: Can you show the full `OrdersScreen` component? As that is probably where you error is.

Comment: @Andrew I edited my question. I don't think it's problem of OrdersScreen. I made a simple test clicking on the button and then navigating (without the redux flow) to the screen, and it worked. It should be something with componentDidUpdate...

Comment: Is `OrdersScreen` different from `OrderScreen`?

Comment: By only showing snippets of code rather than full components you make it hard for someone to debug it. Looking at the error you posted it says `The error is located at: in Connect(OrdersScreen)` my first step is to check the code in the `OrdersScreen`.  You’re asking for other people to find your error but only showing a small piece of the puzzle. I’m afraid I can’t help you. Good luck in your search for a solution.

Comment: @Andrew Sorry, I didn't think it was really necessary, my mistake. I added the full OrdersScreen now. The error now is a bit different because I made some changes.

Comment: @DrewReese No, it isn't, It was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem was related with the misusing of enums in TypeScript.

The reducer actions were created as

```
export enum ProductActionType  {
    LIST_ORDERS
}
```

This resolves my problem:

```
export enum ProductActionType  {
    LIST_ORDERS = "LIST_ORDERS"
}
```